# Proving that a relation is a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$
>
> Prove that $\{(1,a), (2,b), (3,c), (4,d)\}$ is a function using the
>   definitions.

The definitions given by the textbook is

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and let $f : A → B$ be a relation from $A$ to $B$. Then $f$ is called a function iff the following holds.

1. The relation f is **well defined**, that is for all $a ∈ A$ and
   $b_1, b_2 ∈ B$ we have that if $(a,b_1) ∈ f$, then $b_1=b_2$, and
2. 2.The relation f is **totally defined**, that is, for every $a ∈ A$ there is $a,  b ∈ B$ so that $(a,b) ∈ f$.

Comment: So what the heck is your question????  Do it.  You have the definition.  Does it satisfy the definition or doesn't it?

Comment: What part do you find difficult to do here?

Comment: Your 1st and 2nd conditions for relation to be a function could be merged into one. Rather, you should include that the domain $f$ must be $A$.

Comment: Also I think you need to double check condition 1 of your definition. I think it should be "The relation f is well defined, that is for all a ∈ A and b1, b2 ∈ B we have that if (a,b1) ∈ f and (a,b2) ∈ f, then b1=b2)"

Answer (score 1):

> Every element of set $A$ should be mapped to set $B$ exactly once to be function.

Given that $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$

> $$\text{Relation}\space\{(1→a), (2→b), (3→c), (4→d)\}\space \text{is a function.}$$

Note that function means when we give an input the function must give exactly one output in its  domain.